# How to use a Visual Gesture Builder database with Unity3D Plugin?

Tags: unity-game-engine, kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm trying to use a .gbd file from Visual Gesture Builder in my Unity3D scene. I have imported both plugins to Unity( the `Kinect.2.0.1410.19000.unitypackage`and `Kinect.VisualGestureBuilder.2.0.1410.19000.unitypackage`). The included demos and skeleton data work fine.

When tyring to import my gesture database like this:

```
using Windows.Kinect;
using Microsoft.Kinect.VisualGestureBuilder;

void Start () 
{
    _Sensor = KinectSensor.GetDefault();
    // compilation error for the following line, see below
    _gestureDatabase = new VisualGestureBuilderDatabase(@"gestures.gbd");
    // check if sensor is there....
    _gestureFrameSource = new VisualGestureBuilderFrameSource(_Sensor, 0);
    _gestureFrameSource.AddGestures(_gestureDatabase.AvailableGestures);
}
```

Compilation fails:

```
Microsoft.Kinect.VisualGestureBuilder.VisualGestureBuilderDatabase.VisualGestureBuilderDatabase(System.IntPtr)' is inaccessible due to its protection level'
```

and

```
The best overloaded method match for `Microsoft.Kinect.VisualGestureBuilder.VisualGestureBuilderDatabase.VisualGestureBuilderDatabase(System.IntPtr)' has some invalid arguments
```

What am I missing? Is the Kinect API any different in Unity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running into the same problem. As far as I can tell, you cannot call these constructors directly, but you instead need to call on the static method Create. For example, in your case you would say...

```
        _gestureDatabase = VisualGestureBuilderDatabase.Create(@"gestures.gbd");
        _gestureFrameSource = VisualGestureBuilderFrameSource.Create(_Sensor,0);
```

This seems to resolve the issue, at least for me. I'm still running into compilation errors later in the code where I try and retrieve the DiscreteGestureResult, but I'll keep going through the source code looking for answers.

Comment: Thanks for your advise! How did you find out? Is there any documentation on how the Unity plugin is supposed to be used?

Comment: I figured it out by trawling through the source code and trying to understand it. If there is documentation I was unable to find it. This SDK is still relatively new so I suppose its only to be expected.

Comment: FIY there are some more hints at this thread https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/42a4059a-e8b4-4ffd-87e7-757e19dcd7ca/how-to-load-a-vgb-database-with-unity-plugin?forum=kinectv2sdk#4c895477-b120-4806-9f3c-5930b07ac8a1