# Using Kinect gesture detection

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am trying to use gesture detection in my Unity application but I cannot get it to compile. I have trouble instantiating a VisualGestureBuilderFrameSource object.

My investigation has led me to the following posts :

[How to use a Visual Gesture Builder database with Unity3D Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873523/how-to-use-a-visual-gesture-builder-database-with-unity3d-plugin)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/42a4059a-e8b4-4ffd-87e7-757e19dcd7ca/how-to-load-a-vgb-database-with-unity-plugin?forum=kinectv2sdk#4c895477-b120-4806-9f3c-5930b07ac8a1

As explained, I have tried to use the static method Create but I keep getting this error :

*Error CS0117: 'Microsoft.Kinect.VisualGestureBuilder.VisualGestureBuilderFrameSource' does not contain a definition for 'Create' (CS0117) (Assembly-CSharp)*

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah... This is a stupid mistake but hard to recover from once you have done it...

The official VisualGestureBuilder dll does not have Create methods. They were added in a corresponding unity package to allow instantiation of classes such as VisualGestureBuilderFrameSource.

In your unity project, you should **NOT** reference the official Microsoft.Kinect.VisualGestureBuilder.dll but import the VisualGestureBuilder unity package instead. You will find this package in the Kinect plugin for Unity.